# body-component is not a known element using angular quickstart

Tags: angular

I am trying a simple code but I can't make it work. I know a little about angular but this really frustrates me. ;(

app.component.html

```
<body-component></body-component>
```

body.component.html

```
<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './body.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, BodyComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What is wrong here? I got the error body-component is not a known element. Please help.

EDIT:

```
body.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'body-component',
  templateUrl: 'body.component.html'
})
export class BodyComponent  { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Comment: How does `BodyComponent` look like?

Comment: sorry. I added my BodyComponent and AppComponent.

Comment: Can't find a meaningful difference to the code I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'


@Component({
  selector: 'body-component',
  template: `
<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
  `,
})
export class BodyComponent {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <body-component></body-component>
  `,
})
export class App {
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, BodyComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zd4gVdvb8ff1pDYQCzPO?p=preview)

Comment: why use a template? what if I got a really long code? can you reproduce using templateUrl?

Comment: It's just easier in Plunker and I don't think it makes a difference. The style guide says use `templateUrl` / `styleUrls` when the content is more than 3 lines. I think I'm well within these limits :D

Comment: i still got no luck. I have presented my code on top and the only difference I see is that import of NgModule in root app component. But mine is not working.

Comment: Your `BodyComponent` and `AppComponent` are **not** in the same file right? (in this case the order of the classes would matter)